# Erlang: ets select and match performance

Tags: performance, erlang, ets

I find **"The functions ets:select/2 and mnesia:select/3 should be preferred over ets:match/2,ets:match_object/2, and mnesia:match_object/3"** form ref link : http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/tablesDatabases.html

And I'd read some essay about comparing between select and match, I conclude there are some factor effecting the result, such as records' amount in table, select/match a primary key or not, table kind(bag, set...), etc.

In my test, I do for all kind of table with 10W records and 1W records, and only select/match for a un-primary key.

the code following:

```
select_ets_test(Times) ->
    MS = ets:fun2ms(fun(T) when T#ets_haoxian_template.count == 15 -> T end),
    T1 = timer:tc(?MODULE, todo, [fun() -> ets:select(haoxian_test_bag, MS) end, Times]),
    T2 = timer:tc(?MODULE, todo, [fun() -> ets:select(haoxian_test_set, MS) end, Times]),
    T3 = timer:tc(?MODULE, todo, [fun() -> ets:select(haoxian_test_ordered_set, MS) end, Times]),
    T4 = timer:tc(?MODULE, todo, [fun() -> ets:select(haoxian_test_duplicate_bag, MS) end, Times]),
    io:format("select bag           : ~p~n", [T1]),
    io:format("select set           : ~p~n", [T2]),
    io:format("select ordered_set   : ~p~n", [T3]),
    io:format("select duplicate bag : ~p~n", [T4]).

match_ets_test(Times) ->
    MS = #ets_haoxian_template{count = 15, _ = '_' },
    T1 = timer:tc(?MODULE, todo, [fun() -> ets:match_object(haoxian_test_bag, MS) end, Times]),
    T2 = timer:tc(?MODULE, todo, [fun() -> ets:match_object(haoxian_test_set, MS) end, Times]),
    T3 = timer:tc(?MODULE, todo, [fun() -> ets:match_object(haoxian_test_ordered_set, MS) end, Times]),
    T4 = timer:tc(?MODULE, todo, [fun() -> ets:match_object(haoxian_test_duplicate_bag, MS) end, Times]),
    io:format("match bag           : ~p~n", [T1]),
    io:format("match set           : ~p~n", [T2]),
    io:format("match ordered_set   : ~p~n", [T3]),
    io:format("match duplicate bag : ~p~n", [T4]).

todo(_Fun, 0) ->
    ok;
todo(Fun, Times) ->
    Fun(),
    todo(Fun, Times - 1).
```

the record would like: #ets_haoxian_template{type = X, count = Y, ...}, keypose is type.

the resule following:
1W test:

```
insert bag           : {324000,true}
insert set           : {221000,true}
insert ordered_set   : {108000,true}
insert duplicate bag : {173000,true}

select bag           : {284000,ok}
select set           : {255000,ok}
select ordered_set   : {221000,ok}
select duplicate bag : {252000,ok}

match bag           : {238000,ok}
match set           : {192000,ok}
match ordered_set   : {136000,ok}
match duplicate bag : {191000,ok}
```

10W test:

```
insert bag           : {1654000,true}
insert set           : {1684000,true}
insert ordered_set   : {981000,true}
insert duplicate bag : {1769000,true}

select bag           : {3404000,ok}
select set           : {3433000,ok}
select ordered_set   : {2501000,ok}
select duplicate bag : {3678000,ok}

match bag           : {2749000,ok}
match set           : {2927000,ok}
match ordered_set   : {1748000,ok}
match duplicate bag : {2923000,ok}
```

It seem match is better than select? Or my test something wrong???

Comment: This question doesn't look like to me a good fit for StackOverflow; you might have more luck on the erlang-questions mailing list: http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-questions

Answer (score 2):

The `match` function employs a special tuple syntax ([`match_pattern`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#type-match_pattern)) to decide what to return.

The `select` function employs a special tuple syntax ([`match_spec`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#type-match_spec)) that is a superset of `match_pattern`, with the ability to specify guards and extract elements from the result set (rather than just returning the matching keys).

My understanding is that:

- `select` compiles the `match_spec` into something much faster than an anonymous function, executed using the raw C pattern matching engine against ETS data, expediting how fast it runs
- the ability to provide guards to this "function" eliminates false positives quicker than is possible with just a `match_pattern` (since they will run first)
- the ability to extract elements from the result set in-place saves you work you would have to do later, rather than iterating over the returned keys to extract that data.

In trivial non-specific use-cases, `select` is just a lot of work around `match`. In non-trivial more common use-cases, `select` will give you what you really want a lot quicker.